# Devices not getting updated as per minimumVersioCode enforcement on policy

Tags: device-policy-manager, android-management-api, android-enterprise

We have close to around 5000 devices using android management api for its management. We had recently done a minimumVersionCode enforcement on new deployed app version but it seems like 13% of the device is still to be updated to the new version, can anyone help on this and let me know what can be the reason as it has been 10 days when we pushed the minimumVersionCode for our default policy. any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the policy you pushed is already applied to the device. To do so, you can follow these steps:

1. Open play store(if you are using work profile, use the work profile playstore)
2. Open Android Device Policy App
3. Click on the overflow menu (3 dots on the top right)
4. Click on "Device Details"
5. Scroll down and keep tapping Model, until a toast is shown saying debug mode enabled
6. Now go back to the app overflow menu and enable "All policies"

If the policy isn’t already applied, try manually syncing the Android Device Policy app and see if this will update the app. If the policy is already applied please also refer to this [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9350374?hl=en) on app update behaviour to see if a condition could be preventing the update.

Comment: Hi @DavePaurillo,

Thank you for the response and for explaining the steps.
our devices are basically kiosk on an enterprise app and that's our use-case as of now.
However, I can see some of the devices have an updated lastPolicySyncTime but it still has the old version of the app and not the one which was enforced with minimumVersion.
Can you please let us know why are we facing this behavior as the policy seems to be synced already.

Comment: As the policy is already synced, you may refer to this help center article to see if there could be a condition that isn’t met and preventing the app to update.